# Adding new array object to a nested array in react redux reducer and array in store updates but not the react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I am new to React and redux. I have an assignment like adding workflows and inside workflows there are tasks. I am able to add new workflow object to the state array.... but when it comes to adding new task it is directly added to the workflow array, not to the task array. Here is my array structure

```
const initialState = 
{ WORKFLOWS: 
[{ id: 1, Title: 'testdata1', Status: 'Completed',
 Tasks: [{ id: 1, Title: 'Task1', Content: 'Test Content', Status: 'Pending' }, { id: 2, Title: 'Task2', Content: 'Test Content2', Status: 'Pending' }] }, 
{ id: 2, Title: 'testdata2', Status: 'Pending', 
Tasks:[ { id: 2, Title: 'Task1', Content: 'Test Content', Status: 'Pending' }] }], workflowid: 3, isloading: false};
```

and here is my reducers

```
   export const reducer = (state, action) => {
```

state = state || initialState;

```
if (action.type === ADD_WORKFLOW) {

    return {
        ...state,
        WORKFLOWS: [...state.WORKFLOWS, { id: state.workflowid++, Title: 'Workflow' + state.workflowid, Status: 'Pending', Tasks : [] }]
        //WORKFLOWS: [...state.WORKFLOWS, [{ id: state.workflowid++, Title: 'Workflow' + state.workflowid, Status: 'Pending' }]]
    };
   }

if (action.type === EDIT_WORKFLOWTITLE) {
    const index = state.WORKFLOWS.map(item => item.id).indexOf(action.itemid);
    console.log(index);
    return {
        ...state, WORKFLOWS: [...state.WORKFLOWS.map(todo =>
            todo.id === action.itemid ? { ...todo, Title: action.itemtitle } : todo
        )]
    } 
}
if (action.type === EDIT_WORKFLOWSTATUS) {

    return {
        ...state, WORKFLOWS: [...state.WORKFLOWS.map(todo =>
            todo.id === action.itemid ? { ...todo, Status: (todo.Status === 'Pending') ? 'Completed' : 'Pending' } : todo
        )]
    }
}
if (action.type === DELETE_WORKFLOW) {
    const index = state.WORKFLOWS.map(item => item.id).indexOf(action.payload);

    return { ...state, WORKFLOWS: [...state.WORKFLOWS.slice(0, index).concat(state.WORKFLOWS.slice(index + 1))] };
}
if (action.type === ADD_TASK) {
    console.log(state.WORKFLOWS);
    return {
        ...state,
        WORKFLOWS: [...state.WORKFLOWS,
            {
               Tasks: [...state.WORKFLOWS[1], { id: state.workflowid++, Title: 'Workflow' + state.workflowid, Content: 'Workflow' + state.workflowid, Status: 'Pending' }]

        }]


    };

}

  return state;
   };
```

I am facing the issue with add_task action and here is my output when add task is clicked

```
0: {id: 1, Title: "testdata1", Status: "Completed", Tasks: Array(2)}
 1: {id: 2, Title: "testdata2", Status: "Pending", Tasks: Array(1)}
  2: {Tasks: Array(1)}
```

I have also tried the below code array gets the updated but not the view is not updated.

```
   if (action.type === ADD_TASK) {
       let obj = { id: state.workflowid++, Title: 'Workflow' + state.workflowid, Content: 'Workflow' + state.workflowid, Status: 'Pending' };
    let newarray = [];
    newarray = state.WORKFLOWS;
    newarray[1].Tasks.push(obj);
    console.log(newarray);
    console.log(state.WORKFLOWS)
    return {...state, WORKFLOWS: newarray};

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
if (action.type === ADD_TASK) {
    console.log(state.WORKFLOWS);
    return {
    ...state,
        WORKFLOWS: [...state.WORKFLOWS,
                    { id: state.workflowid++, Title: 'Workflow' + state.workflowid, Content: 'Workflow' + state.workflowid, Status: 'Pending', 
                       Tasks: [ { id: 3, Title: 'Task3', Content: 'Test Content', Status: 'Pending' }]
                    }]
      };
}
```

Comment: In general I would recommend you to split `Workflows` and `Tasks` in two reducers and avoid nesting. https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#how-do-i-organize-nested-or-duplicate-data-in-my-state

Comment: I want to add task to a particular workflow... There n number of workflows and inside they contain n number of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

After all my trails. I have created a new array and passed it as a payload in action and assigned it to the state array in redux.

```
 if (action.type === ADD_NEWTASK) {

    state.WORKFLOWS = [];
    return { ...state, WORKFLOWS: action.data };
}
```

It worked for me ... Here what I have done in the component.

```
      addingtask =() => { 
     console.log('Button Clicked');
     let i = this.props.WORKFLOWS[0].Tasks.length;
     let obj = { id: i+1, Title: 'Test' + 1, Content: 'Test' + 2, Status: 'Pending' };
     let newarray = [];
     newarray = this.props.WORKFLOWS;

     newarray[0].Tasks.push(obj);

     this.props.addnewtask(newarray);





}
```